# Текст при передаче его в UITextView через prepareForSegue отображается в очень мелком шрифте

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview

Текст при передаче его в UITextView через prepareForSegue отображается не корректно, в очень мелком шрифте, не помогают ни установленный в сториборде размер шрифта, ни прописание кодом

```
let text = ["ППППРРРР","jnfbkjdnfbk","vcbxjcvnbk"]
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegue" {
        let viewController = ((segue.destinationViewController) as! specialViewController)
        let indexPath = self.specialTableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let specialText = text[indexPath.row]
        viewController.exersiseText = specialText
}
```

В specialViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! 
var exersiseText: String!

Во viewDidLoad

self.aboutExersise.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir Next", size: 25) // Не работает
textView.text = exersiseText
```

А при установке в атрибут инспекторе текствьюшке Selectable (что мне не нужно) отображается корректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в `storyboard` установить `selectable`, а затем во `viewWillAppear` установите

`textview.selectable = false`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. textview.selectable = false